# Is a mismatched "<<" causing my PDF error?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF that can't be opened--when I try to open it in Adobe Acrobat, I get this error:

```
There was an error processing a page. 
There was a problem reading this document (18).
```

When I click Ctrl+OK for more info, I get this message:

```
Expected a name object.
```

Suspecting a corruption problem, I looked through the PDF for mismatched "<<" and ">>" entries (I think these are used to indicate , using this code:

```
public List<int> findUnmatched(string filePath,string leftChars,string rightChars)
{
    string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    List<int> output = new List<int>();
    for (int x = 1; x < fileLines.Length;x++ )
    {
        string fileLine = fileLines[x];
        int leftCount = Regex.Matches(fileLine, leftChars).Count;
        int rightCount = Regex.Matches(fileLine, rightChars).Count;
        if (leftCount != rightCount)
        {
            output.Add(x);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

I found several lines in the PDF that had mismatches, such as this one where there is a `>>` with no opening `<<`:

```
�Uk����6���J�׿�_�@���������)5�үd*�m�?ڏ�N���_���\f7\"�0����:���\f0�W�a?����4_�������o�\b6)�[Kp��T���ʧx`Ȩu�6��A{����p4�����a/�.�A��\v��xD�� �2?^���j��R(��W�I>>�����>�����~�\v�� �̔�V�?��\a���|�����_X��#\f/vK��c��4\v�_A��*��6�D3�O�����~���������dn��m?rX��������ÐqӌE��k�8o��C�z��~��4ߨ`������C�����X����z�g�#�Q��\\!П����_��]o��]�}���o���L&��� ������4c����"
```

But I also looked at the PDF in RUPS and found the following values for `/ID`:

```
/ID: [ß'ÕÒuòµ¤DõíFÖ , t7Ò(lè×Æ`GÒñ]
  $  ß'ÕÒuòµ¤DõíFÖ
  $  t7Ò(lè×Æ`GÒñ
```

So is the mismatched `<< >>` braces the problem, or the `/ID`, or something else?  And how do I fix it--does iTextSharp have functions for correcting this?

Comment: Does `File.ReadAllLines` even mean anything with a PDF file? You tagged `itext`, shouldn't you be using that to try and read the file? It might give a more explicit message of what's wrong versus Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Agree with @Quantic.  Using `File.ReadAllLines` would be influenced by encoding and would probably not give the desired results against a .pdf file.

Comment: Please share the file in question for analysis.

Comment: @mkl, it's a flattened PDF with a lot of proprietary data on it, not sure how to delete that data before I share it.  I was thinking the issue might be related to the `<<` because of your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19910891/619177).

Comment: The problem is that while used as delimiters the double-angled brackets need to be matched, they don't need to match if used inside strings or non-content streams. Furthermore, for a '>>>>' does your code count two or three occurrences? For match counting it should be two.

Comment: @mkl, it finds 2 occurrences.  Looking through the lines returned in `output`, all of them occur inside non-content streams like the one that I listed above (which I guess is graphics data?).  The data for `/ID` looks suspect, though--is that maybe the source of the error?

Comment: The ID looks completely ok. The ID is an array of two byte strings. Thus, looking like garbage characters is completely ok.